# how to put legend outside multiplot gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm using `multiplot` to plot 2 graphics side by side. My graphics use the same legend and he is too big to put in a single column. I want to put outside of multiplot and split them in 5 columns how does it?

I have tried including a new subplot (other column) and in the same subplot (but the graphics are disproportionate).

My script is [here](https://pastebin.com/gVh0Akt6).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the position of the key with

```
set key outside maxcols 2 maxrows 5
```

or

```
set key at <position> maxcols 2 maxrows 5
```

for more help try

```
help key
```

Comment: this no work for me. When I put a key he correspond to a subplot not whole multiplot then one of graphics will be larger than the other. I want to plot 2 graphics (side by side - size proportional to output size) with key below of multiplot